# What risks does giving away the CERTIFICATE credentials to third party?

Tags: android

We at my company work with outsource on our Android application. If the outsource provider has the full source code, is it safe to also provide him with the certificate and its credentials we signing the application's APK with?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 steps of security for Android apps:

1. Source code
2. .jks and credentials
3. Google console access

If you break all three, they can rework and reupload your app to Google Play Store.
Probably, it's bad idea to send them .jks and credentials.

And actually, why do they need that?

Answer (score 0):

The release keystore you use to sign a APK will remain the same across its lifetime. If you are using the [App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en) system, sharing the upload key is less risky, since your Developer console account credentials will remain with you, and you can reset that key.

Even if they have full access to source code, it is better to limit access to certificates and keys in order to avoid impersonation or misuse later, when they may not be working with you. You may also consider [managing permissions for developer account users](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en) to ensure they can only modify what you allow them to.